# 503 Service Unavailable php ошибка

Tags: php, mysqli

Как можно отладить эту ошибку? она возникает через 15 секунд (примерно) после того, как все mysqli запросы уже отработали, и идет вывод информации. Что могло пойти не так?

Comment: Следует залезть в файл логов и посмотреть причину ошибки

Comment: @ArchDemon ошибок  нет совсем

Comment: Как так, нет ошибок, но Вы получаете ошибку?

Comment: @V.March проверил, ровно 300 секунд. Да, серьезно. В логе ошибок выводит все, специально делал некоторые. Просто возвращает код 503 и все

Comment: Значит какой-то процесс длится еще 300 сек после того как все запросы завершились и заканчивается неуспехом доступа? Возможно не все завершились успешно? Может у Вас закрывается коннект в момент когда  с него еще что-то должно грузиться а Вы думаете что все уже отработало? Возможно Ваше оповещение успешного окончания задачи выводится  до того как эта задача завершилась.